# How to order SELECT queries using user-defined functions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function, select, sql-order-by

I want to be able to order data in another way than ORDER BY `columnname`. I read somewhere that it is possible to create your own functions in MySQL. However, I was unable to find a clear explanation of the syntax of how to define such a function, and also how to use it in a SELECT Query.

In essence I want to do:

- Define my own function wich takes two columns as an input, adds them together and returns this number.
- Select data from a table while ordering it by my own defined function and also returning the result of the function back with the rest of the column.

EDIT:

If I have a table like

```
ID | Name | Column1 | Column2 
1   Chris  1234       453
2   John   2341       584
3   Pete   12394      2223
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
SELECT A, B, A+B AS total
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY total
```

Would you please edit your question to show an example of a few sample rows of input data and how you would like the result set to look.

Comment: I did not know that! :D Thanks a lot.  Still, I would love to know how to return and order by the result of a more difficult non-predefined function, say, the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).